# JQuery - What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using Jquery Wookmark as an alternative to Masonry.js but I can't get it to work at all. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <?php include("include/head.php"); ?> // CONTAINS JQUERY 1.9.1
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/posts.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/searches.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.wookmark.js"></script>   
</head>


<div id="postsHolder">
    <div class="post singlePost">
        <div class="postInner">
            <div class="postTop">
                <div class="postTopRow"><strong>Title</strong></div>
            </div>
            <div class="postContentHolder postNoteText">
                Post Information
            </div>
            <div class="postOptions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    x20 (or however many php script specifies)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#postsHolder div').wookmark();
            });
        </script>
```

This is how it appears to tell you to do it on github but I can't get them to block up beneath each other without a huge gap. What do I need to change?

Comment: Please make the title of your question a concise statement of the actual question, something that someone with a similar problem in the future may find on a search.

Comment: is this any css related to wookmark.js

Comment: @Riturajratan Yes but adding that makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

first include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) file

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.wookmark.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#postsHolder div').wookmark();
      });
```

Comment: My JQuery file is included in the `<?php include("include/head.php"); ?>` line

Answer (score 0):

Include Jquery and add css inside the head tag

```
        <html>
        <style>
        .singlePost{
            float: left;
            width: 210px;
        }
        </style>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.wookmark.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postsHolder div').wookmark();
    });
</script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery is already included (as mentioned in comments), all you need to do is wrap your custom script in a [`$( document ).ready()` function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#postsHolder div').wookmark();
    });
</script>
```

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Your CSS declaration at the top will do nothing if it's just plain text. CSS must be placed within the document's `<head>` and must be wrapped within the `style` element:

```html
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .singlePost{
            float: left;
            width: 210px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the .singlePost is in an external css file and is working for the float function. The javascript has now been wrapped in a .ready() function but is still not working. The JQuery is also included above the wookmark script. Any Ideas? I was using Masonry.JS and it was working fine (Except for one technicality which forced me to change it)

Comment: Are any errors being logged in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: No, there are non at all

Comment: Perhaps your selector just needs to be more specific. Rather than using `$('#postsHolder div')` (which targets *all* `div` elements under `#postsHolder`, use `$('#postsHolder > div')` to target only the direct children of `#postsHolider`.

Comment: Thanks but it still makes no difference. Neither does using div.singlePost - Looks like I may have to resort back to using Masonry.js

Answer (score 0):

Your script is in head. And when it is executed maybe postsHolder div not exists. Replace it with function

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#postsHolder div').wookmark();
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** precise selector and add container. This work for me, and without `float:left`.
See container property

```
$(function() {
      // Call the layout function.
      $('#postsHolder .post').wookmark({
        autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
        container: $('body'), // the width of this element is used to calculate the number of columns, defaults to "window". For example $('myContentGrid'). Container should also have the CSS property "position: relative".
        offset: 2, // Optional, the distance between grid items
        itemWidth: 210 // Optional, the width of a grid item
      });
    });
```